# Error getting document: clientDetails Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, updates

What is the reason I am getting this error within a Firestore batch update? The promise is returned as a batch commit and the batches are created inside a loop. I could not get my head around this issue. Any advice?

```
export const updateUserDetailsTypeform = functions.firestore.
  document('responseClientDetails/{case}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const newValue = snap.data();
    const caseReference = snap.id;
    var batch = db.batch();

    var reg = "[^£]*£[^£]*";
    const uid = caseReference.match(reg);
    if (uid && newValue) {

      let document = db.collection("responseClientDetails").doc(caseReference);
      let refDoc = db.collection("clientDetails").doc(uid[0])
      batch.update(refDoc,{ has_seen_setup: "true" })


 document.get().then(function (doc: any) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          let refNo = db.collection("clientDetails").doc(uid[0])
          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(doc.data())) {
            const keyValue = key;
            const valueValue = value;
            batch.update(refNo, { [keyValue]: valueValue })
           // promises.push(db.collection("clientDetails").doc(uid[0]).update({ [keyValue]: valueValue }))
          }

        }else{
          console.log("document does not exist")
        } 
      }).catch(function (error: any) {
        console.log("Error getting document: clientDetails", error);
      });



return batch.commit().then(function () {
  console.log("updated clientDetails")
  return null

});

    }


  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `batch.update(refNo, { [keyValue]: valueValue })` runs asynchronously and is firing after your call to `batch.commit`

Let's clean up your code sample a little and add some comments to help illustrate what happens.

```
// 1 - This fires synchronously
batch.update(db.collection("clientDetails").doc(uid[0]), { has_seen_setup: "true" });

// 2 - This fires synchronously
db.collection("responseClientDetails").doc(caseReference).get().then(function (doc: any) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    let refNo = db.collection("clientDetails").doc(uid[0])
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(doc.data())) {
      const keyValue = key;
      const valueValue = value;
      // 4 - This fires asynchronously AFTER #3 runs, therefore the batch has been committed
      batch.update(refNo, { [keyValue]: valueValue })
    }
  } else {
    console.log("document does not exist")
  }
}).catch(function (error: any) {
  console.log("Error getting document: clientDetails", error);
});

// 3 - This fires synchronously
return batch.commit().then(function () {
  console.log("updated clientDetails")
  return null
});
```

So your fix is probably to move your `batch.commit` call into a `then()` call:

```
batch.update(db.collection("clientDetails").doc(uid[0]), { has_seen_setup: "true" });

db.collection("responseClientDetails").doc(caseReference).get().then(function (doc: any) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    let refNo = db.collection("clientDetails").doc(uid[0])
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(doc.data())) {
      const keyValue = key;
      const valueValue = value;
      batch.update(refNo, { [keyValue]: valueValue })
    }
  } else {
    console.log("document does not exist")
  }
})
.then(() => {
  return batch.commit().then(function () {
    console.log("updated clientDetails")
    return null
  });
})
.catch(function (error: any) {
  console.log("Error getting document: clientDetails", error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to ensure that `batch.commit()` is called only after all the updates have been performed. What your code is doing now is committing before the second update is called.

The problem is that `get()` is asynchronous and is returning immediately before the query is complete. If you add some logging statements, you'll understand better what's going.  What you'll need to do instead is wait until the promise returned from get() is fully resolved before committing the batch.  This means that your call to `batch.commit()` should probably appear inside the `then` callback.